# declaring a const instance of a class

Tags: c++, constants

Let's say I have a class defined as follows:

```
class foo{};
```

now, this is perfectly acceptable;

```
foo f;
```

how come this is a compiler error? (`uninitialized const ‘f’`)

```
const foo f;
```

Why do we have to do this?

```
const foo f = foo();
```

I know why we can't do this..

```
const foo f(); // though it compiles..
```

Interestingly, the following is valid:

```
const std::string f;
```

So what is missing from `foo`?

I realize that there are three questions there and it's bad form, but I'm hoping someone can clear this up for me in one answer.

EDIT: please feel free to close it if it's stupid...

Comment: By the way, I have seen many stupid questions on Stack Overflow. Yours is *not* a stupid question by any means.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I was sitting there scratching my head, and normally when that happens to me, it's inevitably because I've done something stupid... :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your class is a [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) (essentially because it doesn’t provide a default constructor). POD variables are *not* initialized upon declaration. That is, this:

```
foo x;
```

does not initialize x to a meaningful value. This has to be done separately. Now, when you declare it as `const`, this may never happen because you cannot assign to or change `x` any more.

Consider the equivalence to `int`:

```
int x; // legal
const int y; // illegal
```

As you have noticed, using `std::string` instead of `foo` compiles. That’s because `std::string` is not a POD. A simple solution to your dilemma is to provide a default constructor for `foo`:

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() { }
};
```

Now your `const foo x;` code compiles.

Comment: @Konrad what's really interesting is that gcc is the only one that gives an error. When I tried this with other compilers like msvc, CodeGear, and digital mars they all compiled with no complaints. Is this behavior non-standards compliant?

Comment: @Victor: did you really make sure that the `foo` class was a POD (i.e. by having no members at all)? If so, then yes, those compilers are non standards compilant. This code shouldn’t compile.

Comment: @Konrad yes, foo is just an empty struct. I had one version with and without a default constructor. I just tested this with comeau and it correctly catches this too. So it looks like only gcc and comeau are in compliance.

Comment: @Nim: neither did I realize it either, if that's any consolation, guess I have not done enough C...

Comment: @Victor T: Did you check the compilation flags ? MSVC is reknown for its extensions to the standard, and it may simply initialize the struct as if it were a non-POD. I can't recall the equivalent of `-pedantic` for it, but perhaps should you test that ?

Answer (score 6):

Raising an error in the situation of an empty class is a known problem, and reported as [issue #253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253).

Answer (score 1):

`const`, applied to a simple plain-old-data variable, indicates that that variable will not change in that context - so you aren't going to be able to reassign it to something. Therefore, you must initialize it or it will be perpetually uninitialized and thus useless.

Comment: "_applied to a simple plain-old-data variable, indicates that that variable will not change in that context_" and with a non-POD, it means less? ;) [Hint: it doesn't]

Answer (score 1):

I think there are more alternatives. You can do

```
const foo f={};
```

or

```
const foo f(());
```

Const means you can not assign to it later, so you have to initialize it. Since you did not define default constructor the compiler assumes it has to be initialized by you. std::string has default constructor so it is called implicitly by compiler.

Comment: But the two forms are not equivalent in general: the first form will initialise all members of `foo` to 0 (suitably converted), the second form will value-initialise `f`: it will call the default constructor if there is one, either it will value-initialise every member: call the default constructor for the member, if there is one, or value-initialise every member of the aggregate, if it is an aggregate, or initialise the member to 0 (suitably converted).

Comment: “`const foo f(());`” is not valid syntax