# Definition of constant object of class

Tags: c++, class

There is such code:

```
class MojaKlasa{
public:
};

int main()
{
  const MojaKlasa a;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiler error is:

```
error: uninitialized const ‘a’
```

However after modification of class MojaKlasa:

```
class MojaKlasa{
public:
  MojaKlasa(){}
};
```

it works all right. Default constructor should be defined automatically by C++ - why isn't it done in this case and default constructor must be explicitly defined?

Comment: What compiler are you using... The only error I get is unreferenced **a** error

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934457/why-does-const-instance-require-hand-made-default-constructor-gcc-4-2-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934457/why-does-const-instance-require-hand-made-default-constructor-gcc-4-2-1)

Comment: probably a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934457/why-does-const-instance-require-hand-made-default-constructor-gcc-4-2-1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [declaring a const instance of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674332/declaring-a-const-instance-of-a-class)

Answer (score 7):

Draft n3290 (C++0X) has this in §8.5/6:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   — otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>   If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a **const-qualified type T**, T shall be a class type
>   with a **user-provided default constructor**.

So you actually need a user-defined constructor here, the compiler-generated one would not be sufficient.

BTW, `clang++` has a great diagnostic for this:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall t.cpp
t.cpp:7:19: error: default initialization of an object  of const type
                   'const MojaKlasa' requires a user-provided default constructor
  const MojaKlasa a;
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

For C++03, the wording is as follows (§8.5/9):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a user-declared default constructor. Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a non-static object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value ; *if the object or any of its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed*.

Which explains the *why* it is this way. You've got a POD type that you're not initializing,  so its members have an "indeterminate" values. Since the object you declare is `const`, you can't assign to its fields, so you're left with a POD whose values you can't assign to, and you can't read from either (would be undefined behavior). Not very useful.

Comment: +1, though the question remains *why* a user-provided default constructor is required.

Answer (score 2):

When declared as such, `MojaKlasa` is a POD type, so the compiler can't initialize it to any meaningful value automatically, just like it couldn't automatically initialize a `const int` to any meaningful value.

Note that you don't need an explicit default constructor to create constants of this type:

```c
const MojaKlasa foo = {}; // works fine
```

Answer (score -2):

The compiler might be confused because the size of a is zero! Try adding a dummy member to MojaKlasa.

Comment: size of any object must be at least 1 byte, your info is not correct

Comment: The compiler I use, allows for empty classes, whose object size is zero if you provide a special option. Didn't know what the standard says about this. Still what's the use of declaring an object with no constructor that is not refered?

Comment: If a class does not have a constructor, it's members should be initialized using const a = {...}, even if the initialisation list is empty (because 'a' does not have members).