# Trouble with constant objects and functions

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to learn how to use constant functions and objects, however, I have some error that has kept me up for over an hour and I can't seem to figure out. I was following a simple example and I guess I got lost somewhere along the way. Here is my code.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExampleClass.h"

int main(){
    ExampleClass exampleObj; // object used to call members of ExampleClass.
    exampleObj.printText(); // calls printVar from the ExampleClass.

    const ExampleClass constantObject; // object used to call constant members of ExampleClass.
    constantObject.printConstText(); // calls printConstVar from the ExampleClass.

    return 0;
}
```

ExampleClass.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLECLASS_H
#define EXAMPLECLASS_H


class ExampleClass
{
    public:
        void printText();
        void printConstText() const;
};

#endif // EXAMPLECLASS_H
```

ExampleClass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExampleClass.h"

void ExampleClass::printText(){
    std::cout << "The code works!" << "\n";
}

void ExampleClass::printConstText() const{
    std::cout << "The code works!" << "\n";
}
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\ConstObjects\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\ConstObjects\main.cpp|8|error: uninitialized const 'constantObject'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

If I take out the const before ExampleClass the code executes fine. But is it still a constant object? Thanks for the help, I hope I gave enough information. If it matters at all I'm using Code Blocks.

Comment: In case you're misunderstanding, you don't need a constant object to call constant member functions. The relationship is that a constant object can **only** call constant member functions.

Comment: Just a note: You don't need both `printText` and `printConstText`, the `const` method qualifier will make the functions different even if they are named the same.

Comment: The code looks fine, what compiler are you using? Is the code shown really the code, that produces the error message? No &-sign?

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki No, the code isn't fine. The error message is correct. A `const` object must be initialised.

Comment: I know. But, I am trying to learn how to use constant objects. Is it even worth learning if regular objects can call constant functions anyway?

Comment: And yes this is the code that produces the error. I copied it from CodeBlocks and pasted it piece by piece on the question. I copied and pasted the error message too.

Comment: @hvd, I am not sure that the error messasge is relevant. This object does not have data members. What should be inited??

Comment: @LwinHtooKo VC++6 is by no means a standards-conforming C++ compiler.

Comment: @hvd How do I initialize a const object? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @hvd Every object must be initialized, that's not only true for const objects.

Comment: @KirillKobelev The class itself. `= {}` should also work without adding a constructor.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki `int a; a = 3;` is perfectly valid. `a` is never initialised, it's only assigned to.

Comment: For the record, it compiles fine with GCC 4.6.3 and a 4.8 snapshot.

Comment: @hvd, `= {}` is neither wise, nor reasonable. Event if this stated in the standard (?).

Comment: I don't have more recent than 4.5.3 installed here, but that produces the error. Is it possible that C++11 changed the rules and that GCC uses the new rules even in C++98 mode?

Comment: @KirillKobelev What's unwise or unreasonable about it? Anyway, you need that unless you add a constructor.

Comment: This is a default ctor that is automatically generated in many other cases. How putting an empty braces will help?

Comment: @KirillKobelev Without the empty braces, no constructor will get called.

Comment: @hwd, and what? Why implicit ctor can be successfuly called in all other places but not here? What is special? You need to give **reasons**, not just state something that has no base under it.

Comment: @hvd: Yes the rules did change in C++11.

Comment: @KirillKobelev The reasons have already been stated by others, so I didn't feel a need to repeat it. Basically, the (old) standard says a POD class with an implicit constructor doesn't get initialised unless you initialise it. That's why explicitly creating a constructor also works.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Thanks, in that case, I will take a look at the new rules when I get the chance.

Comment: @hvd. Reason == no reason. Great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [declaring a const instance of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674332/declaring-a-const-instance-of-a-class)

Comment: @KirillKobelev The reason why the compiler behaves like that is nothing more than "because the standard says it must". Are you instead asking why the standard is written the way it is?

Comment: @hvd. First, I do not see any references to the stnd above. Second, even standard has gaps and unreasonable statements. Once the standards has a problem (ex: export with templates in C++03), it is necessary to admit that rather than continue saying that everything is right there and does not need reasons. Even standard needs reasons.

Comment: @hvd I guess [this issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) got dealt with in C++11. In any case, with GCC 4.6.3 the code compiles with and without C++11 support.

Comment: @KirillKobelev This comment area is rather limited. Which part would you like? That const objects must be initialised? That POD classes aren't initialised unless you initialise them? That the class in this question is a POD class? And you don't explain why any of this is unreasonable, so I have trouble taking that seriously.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's still listed as "drafting", so it's probably not (completely) resolved in C++11, but Charles Bailey did say the rules changed in C++11, so I'm guessing it's partially resolved?

Comment: @hvd: The requirement for a non-POD class type to have a user-declared constructor if a const-qualified object doesn't have an initializer has been removed as has the requirement for const-qualified objects of POD-class type to have an initializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ExampleClass` is a [POD (plain old data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) structure. When it's declared as a local variable like this `ExampleClass exampleObj` no default constructor gets called and it remains uninitialized.

You need either to create a default constructor of your own or use the following syntax -`ExampleClass exampleObj = ExampleClass();`. This will create a temporary `ExampleClass` object and value initialize your `exampoleObj`.

**updated:**

Here is an excerpt from C++03 standard 8.5.9.

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of
>   (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the
>   object shall be default-initialized;
>
> **if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a
>   user-declared default constructor**. [this one applies to const objects]
>
> **Otherwise, if no initializer is
>   specified for a nonstatic object, the object and its subobjects, if
>   any, have an indeterminate initial value); if the object or any of its
>   subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.** [this one applies to const and POD types]

This means that the `constantObject` should have user-defined default constructor, otherwise a program is ill-formed, which should be diagnosed. If we remove const, the object will remain uninitialized anyway (will have *indeterminate initial value*)

Comment: OP said his code works if he makes the object non-const. So does a default constructor get called in that case?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Not true. If the definition has no initializer, default constructor is called for non-POD class types only. For POD class types (as in this example) the object is simply left uninitialized. The `()` syntax does not call constructor either.

Comment: @AndreyT I don't see a contradiction. The compiler generated default constructor can leave members uninitialized.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: That's correct. However, the standard is very specific about it: constructor is called for non-POD classes only. The rationale is probably to leave the path open for *value-initialization* (instead of constructor call) in response to `()` initializer. For a POD type the `()` does not call constructor, but instead performs *value-initialization*, which is a completely different initialization mechanism.

Comment: @AndreyT: True in C++03; not true in C++11. In C++11 such values are default-initialized which changed meaning in C++11 to mean calling the default constructor which does no initialization. The effect is the same but technically, in C++11, the compiler generated default constructor is called to do no initialization rather than no initialization taking place.

Answer (score 6):

The const object "constantObject" needs an initializer or requires "class ExampleClass" to have a user-declared default constructor.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler generate a default constructor?

Comment: No, by all means! The compiler generates a default constructor for you. Please do not add any code that is pointless and unnecessary it makes code so hard to read.

Comment: If an object of const type is defined without initializer, a *user-declared* default constructor is required.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: The compiler does generate a default constructor. But in this case language requires a default constructor explicitly declared by the user.

Comment: @AndreyT it's not *required*. You can initialize the object without a default constructor

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: You can. However, again, if (as in this case) you define a const object without initializer, the class must have user-declared default constructor. This is a quote straight from the standard. When I say "in this case" I refer to OP's code, in which the const object is defined *without* an initializer.

Comment: It doesn't need a default constructor, you can explicitly initialize constant object: `const ExampleClass = {};`

Comment: @CharlesBailey agreed. This answer is misleading.

Comment: And yes. CodeBlocks creates a constructor upon creation of the class, but I must have deleted it when I was trying to get rid of an old function or something. I didn't realize that I needed the constructor though.

Comment: The const object "constantObject" needs an initializer or requires  to have a user-declared default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is considered and issue and seems to have been fixed, at least in newer versions of GCC, and presumably in the C++11 standard. See [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) for the issue report.